# execute SSIS using .cs code

Tags: c#, ssis

Can you please help me with this piece of code. I am trying to execute a SSIS package which picks up the data from a server and then dumps into another server.  when i run the package manually it works fine, the table is updated. But when I try to using .cs code, nothings happens. Please suggest. below is the code for reference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExecuteSSISPackage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExecSSIS exec = new ExecSSIS();
            exec.execPackage();
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

namespace ExecuteSSISPackage
{
    public class ExecSSIS
    {
        public void execPackage()
        {
            String pkgLocation = @"C:\temp\Perfect_Order\Perfect_Order\Package.dtsx";
            Package ssispackage;
            Application app;
            DTSExecResult result;
          //  Variables vars;

            app = new Application();
            ssispackage = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

            result = ssispackage.Execute();

            if (result == DTSExecResult.Success)
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            else if (result == DTSExecResult.Failure)
                Console.WriteLine("Error");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? Which DTS result do you get?

Comment: I get this error.

'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x4580 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8628] ExecuteSSISPackage.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: That looks normal. Have you debugged it to see which DTS result you get?

Comment: i get this result.

  result Failure Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult

Comment: Couple of obvious things. have you debugged it to make sure the package loads successfully? Does your package have any runtime parameters?

Comment: Yes, The package loads successfully.  No it does not have any parameters. it has the connection managers.

Comment: OK. I can't see an issue with your code. Can you get your package to log event success/failure? Or you could create an Event Handler and try tracking the problem down. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/handling-events-programmatically

Comment: is it possible the c: drive is not on the same machine that you are running your script?